# To get the hierarchical structure from Active directory to power bi

Tags: active-directory, powerbi, connection

I am trying to get the user hierarchy from the active directory to power bi

So, I am facing an error as :
Unable to Connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect. Details: "Active Directory: The active directory domain 'company1.uk' couldn't be found."

So, Can it be possible I can get it from a blank query to get the hierarchical structure or any other way?

If yes, Could you please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact error message in a lab environment and it turned out to be a DNS issue.

The domain controller had a made up domain with a few VMs joined to it. I had configured a domain override in the router's DNS (pfSense router) so that the AD Domain (in your case company1.uk) would defer to the lab domain controller for DNS. My issue was that I spelled it wrong, once I corrected that the error was resolved.

I imagine it would work if you also put specific DNS entries in for the domain and the hosts tied to it that you needed to communicate with.